# How to incorporate time element in logistic regression to build a failure prediction model?

Tags: regression, logistic

I would like to build a model that can predict the probability of failure for individual components of a system. What I have is historical data of component failures recorded in the last 30 years. I am thinking of formulating the problem as a binary classification (Failure: 1, Non-failure: 0) using logistic regression. The challenge, however, is the nature of the data, illustrated in the figure below.

[image]

As you can see in the figure, the components in the system were not all installed at the same time. Moreover, some of the components failed quickly compared to the others. Further, there are right-censored data (all components that have not failed). Even though I am only interested in the probability of failure and not the exact "time-to-failure" for individual components, I would like to somehow incorporate the time element in my model for three main reasons (in addition to addressing the different data types):

1. I would like the predicted probability of failure to be for the next n-specified years e.g. probability of failure of Component X within the next 5 years is p. My understanding could be wrong here but if I considered the entire 30-year period the prediction will be for the next 30 years, correct?
2. I would like to somehow incorporate the concept of component degradation over time in the model.
3. To explore if the effects of predictors vary over time.

To incorporate the time aspect, I am thinking of breaking the 30-year period into shorter study intervals and doing progressive logistic regression (left to right in the figure). I have seen similar concepts with pooled logistic regression and repeated measures logistic regression (Wu and Ware, 1979), but I wanted to check if this approach actually does address the concerns that I have. Also, I wanted to ask if I can add predictions from the model from the preceding time interval as input (degradation term proxy) to the following model. What kind of challenges does this bring?

Comment: This sounds like a [tag:survival] analysis task.

Comment: @Sycorax I could be wrong but the studies that have used survival analysis for time-to-event usually predict for a group of components and not for individual components. I am interested in predictions for individual components.

Comment: What's the distinction that you're making between a group and an individual component?

Comment: By group, I mean components grouped based on a shared attribute or property e.g. components made out of steel or component made of iron. Most (or all) applications of survival analysis that I have come across predict failure rates for these groups. There is no distinction of failure rates within the individual components within a group.

Comment: I don't see how this precludes whether or not this is a survival analysis task. You're trying to estimate the probability of failure given that some amount of time has elapsed, which is a question of how much probability is in the tail of some CDF, i.e. a survival function.

Comment: To be clear here, I am not a stat major and I have limited knowledge in these topics. All I am stating is what I have seen in different research articles I have read and I could be wrong. If you could direct me to works that have done individual component success/failure analysis or to resources that describe how that can be done would be really helpful. However, I would still like to know what are the weak points with using logistic regression in the above setting.

Comment: Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* has a chapter entitled "Introduction to Survival Analysis." He writes "Suppose that one wished to study the occurrence of some event in a population of subjects. If the time until the occurrence of the event were unimportant, the event could be analyzed as a binary outcome using the logistic regression model... In a study of emphysema, death at eight years after onset of symptoms is different from death at six months. An analysis that simply counted the number of deaths would be discarding valuable information and sacrificing statistical power."

Comment: We also have a number of threads enumerating references about survival analysis: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survival+references